# Download file using requests python

Tags: python, for-loop, download, python-requests, torrent

I have a list of Url of files that open as Download Dialogue box with an option to save and open.
I'm using the python requests module to download the files. While using Python IDLE I'm able to download the file with the below code.

```
link = fileurl
r = requests.get(link,allow_redirects=True)
with open ("a.torrent",'wb') as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

But when I use this code along with for loop, the file which gets downloaded is corrupted or says unable to open.

```
for link in links:
    name = str(links.index(link)) ++ ".torrent"
    r = requests.get(link,allow_redirects=True)
    with open (name,'wb') as code:
        code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Check the status of the requests before writing to the file.

Comment: I think this has more to do with the other components you're working with. Could you describe the environment around this code snippet a bit more clearly/completely?

Comment: because you are rewriting the same file again and again

Comment: @rdas I get status code as 200

Comment: @NikolayPatarov I have tried writing diff filename. but it haven't helped

Comment: @Richard I'm just using basic Python IDLE, I am scraping list of torrent links and adding to a URL list, with which I open every file individually to download.

Comment: What do the torrent files look like in a hex editor if you open them?  The second code example works (if you fix the `++` typo), leading me to suspect the site is blocking Python somehow.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to download a video from a website, try

```
r = get(video_link, stream=True)
with open ("a.mp4",'wb') as code:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        file.write(chunk)
```

Comment: its not a stream file, it's a ".torrent" file

Comment: That doesn't really matter as such.